# Can't get music to play in Doomsday 1.10.2 in Ubuntu Precise

Tags: music

I had an older version of the Doomsday engine, and I got the music and sound effects just fine.  I recently upgraded to the 1.10.2 version with all the extras and although I have the sound effects, nothing I do seems to be able to get the music to play.  I've Googled every possible permutation of "Doomsday" "Ubuntu" "Linux" and "Music" and I've come up empty.  Anyone have any ideas?

I have the WAD files for the full commercial versions of Doom, Doom2, Heretic AND Hexen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem using Linux Mint 16 and Doomsday 1.12 and I searched on doomsday engine forum, found [this topic](http://dengine.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1572&hilit=music).

I downloaded and installed the addons Doom Classic Music and Doom2 Cmassic Music and now the music works fine.